# OpenGeneric support in MEF application

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, mef

I have taken a reference from http://pwlodek.blogspot.in/2010/12/introduction-to-interceptingcatalog.html

It is a very good example but I am bit confused in using of this code.
I am creating a WPF + Prism + MEF Application where I am defining all the dependency like it is define in "Stock Trader RI" Example 
as per the Stock Trader RI I am Initializing all the module into MyBootstrapper class.
In my project I have a requirement to support of Open Generic like it is provided in above link example .
Now my question is where do I Implement example code, I am trying to implement it into MyBootstrapper ConfigureAggregateCatalog() method

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public partial class ImsBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
      protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
      {

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (ImsBootstrapper).Assembly));

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (ImsCommands).Assembly));

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (DalModel).Assembly));

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (TestClass).Assembly));

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (TestClassImp).Assembly));



          // Create source catalog
          var typeCatalog = new TypeCatalog((typeof(RegistrationViewModel)));

          // Create catalog which supports open-generics, pass in the registry
          var genericCatalog = new GenericCatalog(new MyGenericContractRegistry());

          // Aggregate both catalogs
          var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(typeCatalog, genericCatalog);

          // Create the container
          //var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
          this.Container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog); 

          this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(StudentModel).Assembly));

      }
```

but it is not working could you please guide me Where do I use example Given in above link to get open generic(Example of Open Generic Public Class Repository: IRepository) support

1. In a BootStrapper
2. or some were else

If you are still confused about my question just give me an example How do i get OpenGeneric Support in "Stock Trader RI" demo application comes for prism using "MefContrib" I am trying to achieve this by following  example given in this link http://pwlodek.blogspot.in/2010/12/introduction-to-interceptingcatalog.html but got confused where to call this code Wather in MyBootstrapper or some were else.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use .NET 4.5. Support for open generics is already part of MEF in that version, you don't need to do anything special. See [What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

.NET 4.5 has not yet been released, but the release candidate is [already available under a "go live" license](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads/go-live). This means that  you may already use it in production.

**edit**: if you cannot use .NET 4.5, you can still download and use the latest MEF2 preview from [mef.codeplex.com](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/79090). For example, [MEF2 Preview 5](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/79090) supports open generics and will work on .NET4.

Comment: Due to some business requirement i cannot use .net framework4.5 please suggest another solution

Comment: I have downloaded and added to my application now it is giving another error ErrorThe type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.D:\Projects\GurukulDSK\Institute Management System Prism\ImsRichui\ImsBootstrapper.csImsRichui   It is giving this error because Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.dll dose not have this assimbly reference and my bootstrapper usering MEFBootbootstrapper